# Angular DataTables with ajax function- $http

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I create ***data table with ajax*** in Angular.

The code:

```
app.controller('WithAjaxCtrl', WithAjaxCtrl);

function WithAjaxCtrl($scope,DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,$http) {

    $scope.dateFrom = {value:new Date()}
    $scope.dateTo ={value:new Date()}

//the http success callback return the data
        var successCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }

//the http error callback 
    var errorCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
       alert('fail with status '+status)
    }

//The http fuction
        var getRecord = function () {
            var from =  $scope.dateFrom.value;
            var to = $scope.dateTo.value;
            $http.post('/loadRecord/'+from+'/'+to)
                .success(successCallback).error(errorCallback)
        }

//The data tables function
        $scope.filterByDate=function(){
            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(getRecord())
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        }

    var vm = this;
    var from =  $scope.dateFrom.value;
    var to = $scope.dateTo.value;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(getRecord())
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withOption('responsive', true);
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('xxxx').withTitle('XXXX),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('yyy').withTitle('YYY),

    ];

}
```

the HTML code:

```
  <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns"
                   class="row-border hover"></table>
```

The $http call work successfully.

But nothing incoming into the table!

I think that nothing return from the function but I dont know **where can I put the *return* with the data**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build the options normally like this

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(2);
vm.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible(),
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2).notSortable()
];
```

then retrieve the data that needs to be passed on to the table with `$http` call

```
$http.post(url,params).then(function success(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            });
```

and finally use ngRepeat to create your table

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in data">
        <td>{{ obj.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.xxxx }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.yyyy }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Remember to fix the string literals in the last statement in ctrl

```
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('xxxx').withTitle('XXXX),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('yyy').withTitle('YYY),

];
```

Here `'XXXX` should `'XXXX'`

Similar example is in the datables [docs](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayWithOptions)

Comment: It fell with this error [err link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=showcase.withAjax&…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381) What can I do?

Comment: It Work, but it is takes time to load the data